# How to read array data using where condition

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have stored one query result in an php array

```
 Array
 (
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [AccountNumber] => 1000000
            [FirstName] => james
            [LastName] => James Administrator
        )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [AccountNumber] => 1000001
        [FirstName] => george
        [LastName] => James
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [AccountNumber] => 1000002
        [FirstName] => Clara
        [LastName] => Pradeep 
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [AccountNumber] => 1000003
        [FirstName] => Dona
        [LastName] => Kodi
    )
```

)

I needs to print FirstName and LastName for a particular  AccountNumber

### excepted output is:

FirstName: Clara

LastName: Pradeep

where AccountNumber is 1000002

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried.

Comment: You indicated this is coming from a database. Why not just use the db's 'where clause' functionality?  Then you end up with only the matching result. Plus, it's going to be faster because you transmit less data from the db and don't have to pull the results, then loop through them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search through the array for the account number you want, and then output:

```
$object_array = {your array}; // whatever variable you have to print out what you posted
foreach ($object_array as $account) {
    if ($account->AccountNumber == "1000002") { // change the number to a variable if required
        echo "<p>FirstName: " . $account->FirstName . "</p>";
        echo "<p>:LastName: " . $account->LastName . "</p>";
    }
}
```